# T-SQL GO in UPDATE statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a single derived field that is populated by a series of update statements, each statement joining to a different table and different fields.   It is important that the series of updates execute in a specific order, i.e. a join to table A may produce result X then a join to table B produces result Y in which case I want result Y.   Normally I just create a series of Update statments in the appropriate order and store them either in a single SSIS SQL container or in a single stored procedure.  Is there a best practice regarding using or not using a GO command or BEGIN END between these update statements?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think consecutive statements would be executed out of order? Do you have specific locking hints on any of the statements (e.g. `UPDLOCK`, `HOLDLOCK`, etc.)? Otherwise if you have two consecutive statements, A and B, and A changes something, B will see that change. How that works in SSIS may be different if you have some branching or multi-threading capabilities, but this is not possible in a stored procedure.

Also `GO` is not a T-SQL command, it is a batch separator recognized by certain client tools like Management Studio. If you try to put a `GO` between two statements in a stored procedure, one of two things will happen:

1. the procedure will fail to compile (if the opening `BEGIN` doesn't have a matching `END` right before the `GO`).
2. the procedure will compile (if there is no `BEGIN/END` wrapper), but it will be shorter than you thought, ending at the first `GO` rather than where you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Statements are executed in exactly the order that you write them in. You don't need `GO` or `BEGIN...END` to ensure ordering. For that reason using either of these has no effect. They also have nothing to do with transactions.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. The updates that I currently working on involve some large tables and joining across multiple servers and databases so I wanted to make it as efficient as possible. I saw the thread T-SQL GO Statement that mentions log size, smaller batches, and transactions.  Then I recalled in SS 2000 DTS where I added an additional update within a step and the package never recognized that I had made the change.  I finally split it out into separate containers/transactions (not sure of the approp terminology there.)  So I wondered if there was some connection there.